# taking whole height in flutter while keeping some height for other widget

Tags: dart, flutter

The top section can grow and shrink based on data coming from server, the middle section is map and takes whole height available while keeping some space for a button. Any ideas how can I achieve this?
[image]

Comment: I'd check out the [Flexible](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) and [Expanded](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) Widgets as they'd be able to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Column` combined with `Expanded`

```
Column(
  children: [
    Text('Top'),
    Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.red)),
    Text('bottom'),       
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand what you want but If you want to show data no matter the size of the data you wanted the show

you can use [SingleChildScrollView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html)

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: YourGrowAbleWidgetHere()
),
```

able the scroll